# Repeating an entry on the result of a get request in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to populate a list in angular based on the returned result of a get request to my back end.

I have the following implementation but it is not populating. The call is being made to the back end, the view is however not being populated

View:

```
 <div ng-controller="MyController as controller">
     <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="page in myPages">
                Test
            </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

MyController:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    function MyController($scope, $stateParams, MyService) {
          $scope.init = function() {
            $scope.myService = MyService;
            $scope.myPages = $scope.getPages();
          }
          $scope.getPages = function() {
            return $scope.myService.getPages(null);
          }

          $scope.init();
    }
    MyController.$inject = ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$MyService'];
    angular.module('MyModule').controller('MyController', MyController);
})();
```

MyService:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    function $MyService($http, API_CONFIG) {
        function getPages(active) {
            return $http.get('my/url', {
                params: {
                      activeOnly : active
                }
            });
        }
        return { getPages : getPages } 
    }
    $MyService.$inject = ['$http', 'API_CONFIG'];
    angular.module('myServiceModule', []);
    angular.module('myServiceModule').factory('MyService', $MyService);
}
```